# Android Search Functionality; Displaying Results in Original Activity?

Tags: android

My app has a MainActivity that includes a search button (among many of the other main components). Upon clicking the search button, OnSearchRequested() is called and SearchableActivity does the searching and returning of the results. Now that I have the results, I want a ListView to appear in the MainActivity, NOT in the Searchable Activity.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off using an asynctask instead of a new activity. If you must use an activity, you could use startActivityForResult

Answer (score 0):

After the SearchActivity returns the query and before you do the searching you could create an intent and add the query as an extra like the following:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("SEARCH_QUERY", query);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then in your MainActivity you could check for that extra:

```
getIntent().getStringExtra("SEARCH_QUERY")
```

if its not null or blank do your search and hand your results to your listView adapter, else do what ever else your MainActivity is doing.

Assuming you have the same type of data in each of your lists, I would suggest creating a list fragment that both your main activity and search activity would use.